# How to make an ethernet cable with a broken clip usable?

Tags: cables

The red marked part of my Ethernet Cable is broken and the plug won't stay inside of the port, so is there a workaround for that problem?

**Note:** Buying a new cable is no workaround! :D

[image: img1]

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is considered buying a new cable: I would cut off the old plug and crimp on a new one.  The connectors are dirt cheap, but the crimping tool can be expensive, so you'll want to borrow one, if possible.

**Amazon** `UbiGear Network Tool Kit`:

[image]

Comment: regardless of whether this has a cost to it, this is "the right way" to do it. (but if you do it wrong, the connection will be unreliable... test it with the tester (seen in top left of picture) while pulling the cable in each direction for at least one run of the lights. Also be sure to buy the right ends. The linked one is for cat 5e, not cat6 which has an extra ground.

Answer (score 5):

You always have the option of using gaffa or duct tape to fasten it, and if you don't want to fasten it in the computer end then simply reverse the cable.

If you don't like using tape on the cable, reversing could still be an option as it might be less tension in the other end. You could also opt for using a tooth pick or similar to apply a little pressure within the contact. Do take care not to destroy the contact, as that will me a lot more costly rather than replacing the cable.

Answer (score 3):

In the past I've just folded a bit of paper --- enough to provide a bit of tension when the plug goes in.  Doesn't take much to wedge something on the non-contact side to keep it firmly implanted and is good in an emergency. Of course if you want a permanent fix, a new cable or terminal end as suggested above would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, my answer involves DUCT TAPE!

Take a small piece of DUCT TAPE and place it over the top side of the connector on the side where the clip would be.  Repeat until you have built up enough material so that it goes in and stays in.

Honestly though, these cables are so cheap you should just buy a new one, or reterminate it (but that's way more expensive unless you know someone with the tools).  Alternatively you could just ship it to me and let me reterminate it for you...

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this Question,
if that happens to me i just take a match and put it at the point, where the clipper was supposed to be and press it into the computer.